# Gradle: Overwrite file in WAR

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to replace a file in WAR file generated with Gradle.

Files structure:

```
- nodes
  - staging
    - localConfig.yml
    - logback.groovy
- grails-app
  - conf
    - application.yml
    - logback.groovy
```

I want to copy files from `nodes/staging` to `WEB-INF/classes` in the final WAR when I execute gradle script with parameter `-Pnode=staging`.

This is my approach:

```
war {
    if (project.hasProperty('node')) {
        from("stacks/${project.node}") {
            include('localConfig.yml')
            include('logback.groovy')
            into('WEB-INF/classes')
        }
    }
}
```

This gradle script will copy `localConfig.yml` to `WEB-INF/classes`, however the `logback.groovy` is not replaced.

How can I set up gradle to replace duplicate files instead of keeping the original ones?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use the [classpath method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:classpath) to add to `WEB-INF/classes`
eg:

```
war {
    if (project.hasProperty('node')) {
        classpath "stacks/${project.node}/localConfig.yml", "stacks/${project.node}/logback.groovy"
    }
}
```

Or perhaps

```
war {
    if (project.hasProperty('node')) {
        classpath fileTree("stacks/${project.node}")
    }
}
```